# Detected memory leaks in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

The following declaration in the file generated by grpc (grpc.pb.cc) causes a memory leak.
It seems that google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary() does not free the memory allocated by this declaration.
Would you tell me how to release it?

```
PROTOBUF_ATTRIBUTE_INIT_PRIORITY static ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AddDescriptorsRunner dynamic_init_dummy_DxpGrpc_2eproto(&descriptor_table_DxpGrpc_2eproto);
```

Windows, C ++, gRPC-1.40.0

Create a console application in the Windows c++ environment and execute the following code.

```
#include <crtdbg.h>.
#include "google/protobuf/service.h";

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

The following leaks will be out.

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects -> {159}
{Normal block at 0x00E49B18, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < k > 10 6B C9 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

When declare AddDescriptorsRunner in grpc.pb.cc, it calls DefaultConstruct() of the following class.

(File: third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\message_lite.h)

```
template <typename T>.
class ExplicitlyConstructed {
 public:
  void DefaultConstruct() { new (&union_) T(); }
  template <typename... Args>
  void Construct(Args&&... args) {
    new (&union_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) ;
  }

  void Destruct() { get_mutable()->~T(); }

  constexpr const T& get() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(union_); }
  T* get_mutable() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&union_); }

 private:
  // Prefer c++14 aligned_storage, but for compatibility this will do.
  union AlignedUnion {
    alignas(T) char space[sizeof(T)];
    int64 align_to_int64;
    void* align_to_ptr;
  } union_;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static or global object is freed the very last thing, after `atexit`, and the debugger reports false leak. This behavior can be reproduced with this example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
std::string str;
int main() 
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();//str is not freed yet
    return 0;
}
```

You can create a structure and place the leak report in the destructor, as shown below. Note in this example, `std::string str;` is used to cause a leak report.

If `cleanup` is not defined, or if `cleanup` is defined after `std::string str;` then false leak is reported. The order of definition matters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

struct cleanup_t
{ 
    ~cleanup_t() { if(IsDebuggerPresent()) _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }
} cleanup;

std::string str;

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not yet solved. I mistake debug.
It is true that leaks can occur in the order of declarations, but I can't determine if this is the case.
I have defined the "cleanup" structure as described and checked it, but the leak still occurs.

I tried before and after the following declarations that indicated the leak was occurring, and it did.

PROTOBUF_ATTRIBUTE_INIT_PRIORITY static ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AddDescriptorsRunner dynamic_init_dummy_DxpGrpc_2eproto(&descriptor_table_DxpGrpc_2eproto);

Comment: Put a debug break point in `void Destruct(){...}` to make sure `new (&union_)` is balanced by `delete`, add another break point for leak-report.

Comment: 'void Destruct()' will never be called. 'DestroyString(const void* s)' in the following code is called by 'google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();'. 's' is the address of union, so I think that the release process will be executed on this.(third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\generated_message_util.cc)'google::protobuf::internal::DestroyString(const void* s) { static_cast<const std::string*>(s)->~basic_string();}'